# Does LIBSVM take care of missing values in training?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, svm, libsvm

I am working on multivariate regression using libsvm. I have some data with missing values. For example, I have 10 instances of 10 nodes and each node 10 links associated with it. I need to train these 10 nodes using the 10 instances. But in some instances some of the links values are missing. So how does libsvm treat them? or do I need to fill those missing values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the  [libsvm FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#/Q3%3a_Data_preparation), the question "Why sometimes not all attributes of a data appear in the training/model files?". Missing values area treated as zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am LIBSVM toolbox in matlab which I am not using sparse format. So I think I need to fill those values

Comment: If you use libsvm with matlab, it calling function with mex, so it the same. It's using the C code.